# Wrong Screen Resolution on an Intel D510MO

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics, resolution

I've installed 11.04 onto a Intel D510MO, everything works except I can't change to resolution to anything better than 1024x768. The monitor is capable of supporting 1280x1024. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem using linux mint 11 (Ubuntu based) on a D510MO board and scratched my head for a while over it.
This is because the D510MO has an internal connector for a laptop display panel and it thinks that that is the display that is the primary and mirroring it to the vga output.
Unfortunately because nothing is connected to the internal connector it defaults the resolution to a basic svga.
What you need to do is go to your monitor settings if you have an applet for it and turn off mirror screens or same image on both monitors. Disable the laptop display and make the monitor the primary. Then all works fine.
I now have a 22" monitor and 1680x1024 resolution. Lovely...

Answer (score 0):

This works in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Launcher > System Settings > Displays. Turn off mirror displays then disable the laptop display and set the new resolution option on the detected VGA display. Straight forward. I'm using Intel D510MO motherboard with 2GB SDRAM. Thanks Darron for the tip.